# If git commit IDs are SHA-1 outputs, and SHA-1 produces 160 bits output, why are git commit IDs 320 bits?

Tags: git, git-commit, sha1, sha

```
commit 371a5e1b79515b13237a7cf88538eebfca028d9f (HEAD -> master-fix, origin/master-fix)
Author: Krishna Birla <contributor email>
Date:   Tue Jul 13 18:31:13 2021 +0530

    <commit message>
```

The commit ID is 40 bytes (320 bits). But git uses SHA-1, and SHA-1 produces 160 bits. How?

Comment: Aah, okay. I was assuming one byte per character. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

That is 40 hexadecimal chars.... each char (in hexadecimal) is 4 bits:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
.
.
.
9 = 1001
a = 1010
.
.
f = 1111
```

.... so 40x4 = 160 bits.

Comment: Correct, I was assuming in terms of 1 char = 1 byte. Ofc we only need 1/2 byte for each hexa digit. Thanks!